# Reducing buffer object size

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

What i have now

```
#define QUAD_VERT_COUNT 4

#define QUAD_POS_COMP 3

typedef struct quad_pos
{
 GLfloat x, y, z;
}quad_pos;

#define SIZE_QUAD_POS = sizeof(quad_pos) * QUAD_VERT_COUNT

static QUAD_BUFFER = 0;

void init_quad_buffer()
{
 quad_pos* pos_data = malloc(SIZE_QUAD_POS);

 pos_data[0].x = -1.0f;
 pos_data[0].y = -1.0f;
 pos_data[0].z = 0.0f;

 pos_data[1].x = 1.0f;
 pos_data[1].y = -1.0f;
 pos_data[1].z = 0.0f;

 pos_data[2].x = -1.0f;
 pos_data[2].y = 1.0f;
 pos_data[2].z = 0.0f;

 pos_data[3].x = 1.0f;
 pos_data[3].y = 1.0f;
 pos_data[3].z = 0.0f;

 QUAD_BUFFER = create_buffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_STATIC_DRAW, pos_data, SIZE_QUAD_POS);
 free(pos_data);
}

void get_quad_buffer
{
  return QUAD_BUFFER;
}
```

And drawning (part of it)

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, get_quad_buffer());
glEnableVertexAttribArray(ss->attrib[0]);//attrib[o] is vertex pos
glVertexAttribPointer(ss->attrib[0], QUAD_POS_COMP, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, QUAD_VERT_COUNT);
```

Scaling, translating and rotating achieved with matrices and shaders, so yes this buffer never changes for every sprite.

But why we need to use GL_float for just -1.0, 1.0? GL_Byte will be enough.

```
 typedef struct quad_pos
 {
 GLbyte x, y, z;
 }quad_pos;

void init_quad_buffer()
{
 quad_pos* pos_data = malloc(SIZE_QUAD_POS);

 pos_data[0].x = -1;
 pos_data[0].y = -1;
 pos_data[0].z = 0;
 ....
}
```

Drawning

```
  ...
  glVertexAttribPointer(ss->attrib[0], QUAD_POS_COMP, GL_BYTE, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
  glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, QUAD_VERT_COUNT);
```

**Question 1:** Do i need normalize set to GL_TRUE?
**Question 2:** GLclampf and GLfloat both 4 byted floats, but color values are from 0.0 to 1.0 so if i put them in GLbyte too (val/256, so 255 for 1.0, 128 for 0.5, 0 for 0) do i need GL_TRUE for normalize in glVertexAttribPointer?
**Question 3:** Do i really need padding in vertex data/other data? Adding fictitious pos_data.g, just for sizeof(pos_data) = 16 == Good for gpu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But why we need to use GL_float for just -1.0, 1.0? GL_Byte will be enough.

Please note this is not true in general, in most cases you will need a float for precision. And if you only have so few values and so simple geometry, the odds are quite high that there even isn't a reason at all to optimize it to `glByte` in the first place. You likely have very few vertices at all, so why would you want to save storage on them? This sounds like a very good example of premature optimization (I know, it's an overused term).

Now, for your actual questions:

1. No, not if you want the same functionality, if normalize is false, the `-1` will convert to `-1.0f`, if it is true it will be more something like `-0.0078125f` (or `-1/128.0f`). So if you want to keep the same scale, you don't want it normalized.
2. Where do you get the idea that GLclampf and GLfloat are 8-byte floats? They are usually 4 byte floats. If you want to pass in RGB colors through vertex attributes, yes you should normalize them as OpenGL expects color components to be in the range `[0.0f,1.0f]`. But again: why don't you simply pass them as floats? What do you think to gain? In a simple game you probably have not enough colors to notice the difference and in a non-simple game you're more likely to be using textures.
3. Of this I am not sure. I know it was true for old GPU's (and I mean almost 10y back), but I don't know of any recent claims that this would actually improve something. And in any case, the best-known alignment was to prop all vertex-attributes for one vertex together into (a multiple of) 32 bytes, and that was for ATI cards. Byte alignment might be necessary for some trickier things/extensions, but I do not think you need to worry about it just yet.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you could always aim for the half-float (16bit float) extensions to save memory.

Your implementation looks like causing some draw-call overhead. Normalizing (on the fly!) will cause additional overhead. For drawing multiple instances of this constant quad, I recommend the following to speed things up:

- Implementation of a **geometry-shader**; let it generate, transform and emit the 4 vertices of the quad for you.
- **instanced drawing** with a transform-buffer using a **texture buffer object** (TBO) containing the transform matrices for each quad instance (each matrix column will be accessed using the builtin uniform 'gl_InstanceID').

  OR:
  Supply the matrices via **vertex attribute arrays** (probably faster).
  These two approaches can be implemented upon the same buffer data layout (just an array of matrices)